# Primefaces 5 AjaxBehavior to Chart programaticly

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, charts, xhtml

I tried to create charts dynamically in primefaces, it works fine, but when i want to add ajax behavior to the component, the event is not firing. What is the problem with my code?

Here is what i would like to create dynamically in java:

```
<p:panel>
                    <p:pieChart id="chart_id" rendered="true" value="#{index.pieChart}" legendPosition="w" showDataLabels="true" dataFormat="value"/>
                    <p:resizable for="chart_id">
                        <p:ajax event="resize" listener="#{index.onResize}" />
                    </p:resizable>
                </p:panel>
```

This is the event handler:

```
public void onResize(ResizeEvent event){
   //Some code
}
```

I tried a lot of ways, but i think that would the correct way to create the behavior and components:

```
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application ap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
    Panel panel = (Panel)ap.createComponent(fc, "org.primefaces.component.Panel","org.primefaces.component.PanelRenderer");
    PieChart pieChart = (PieChart)ap.createComponent(fc, "org.primefaces.component.chart.PieChart", "org.primefaces.component.chart.PieChartRenderer");
    pieChart.setId("chart_id");
    pieChart.setRendered(true);
    PieChartModel mod = new PieChartModel();
    mod.set("category1", 32);
    mod.set("category2", 46);
    pieChart.setValue(mod);
    pieChart.setLegendPosition("w");
    pieChart.setShowDataLabels(true);
    pieChart.setDataFormat("value");
    panel.getChildren().add(pieChart);

    Resizable resizable = (Resizable)ap.createComponent(fc, "org.primefaces.component.Resizable","org.primefaces.component.ResizableRenderer");
    resizable.setFor("chart_id");
    AjaxBehavior resizeBehavior = (AjaxBehavior)ap.createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
    MethodExpression listener = ap.getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(fc.getELContext(), "#{index.onResize}", void.class, new Class[0]);
    MethodExpression listenerWithArgs = ap.getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(fc.getELContext(), "#{index.onResize}", void.class, new Class[]{ResizeEvent.class});
    resizeBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(listener, listenerWithArgs));
   resizeBehavior.setListener(listenerWithArgs);
    resizable.addClientBehavior("resize", resizeBehavior);
    panel.getChildren().add(resizable);
    return panel;
```